# Using JavaScript in a HTML5 page to connect to a SQLite database

Tags: javascript, sqlite, html

I'm trying to make a simple word game that has a database of words (which is preloaded or can be loaded by the user) that can be updated through website. I found [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_web_sql.htm) example and I got it to work. However, it wont work if I have an existing database. I'm new to this type of programming, so i've been doing research for 2 days now.

```
var db = openDatabase('db.sqlite', '1.0', 'Test DB', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
var msg;
/*
db.transaction(function (tx) {
tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS vocabList(id unique, word, definition, weekNO)');
msg = '<p>Log message created and row inserted.</p>';
document.querySelector('#status').innerHTML =  msg;
});
*/
```

I commented this out to prevent creating the database (should i have not done that?)

```
db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM vocabList WHERE weekNO = 1', [], function(tx, results) {
        var len = results.rows.length,
            i;
        msg = "<p>Found rows: " + len + "</p>";
        document.querySelector('#status').innerHTML += msg;
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            msg = "<p><b>" + results.rows.item(i).word + "</b></p>";
            document.querySelector('#status').innerHTML += msg;
        }
    }, null);
});
```

If there is another more efficient way to do this, please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're having problems with.  But in your code, you commented out the part where it checks whether or not a table has been created.  From that commented out code, there are no rows being inserted either, so it is a blank database.

I modified your code here: http://jsfiddle.net/Ae8m2/

I uncommented out your creation part, and added a couple rows.

Comment: hi vigrond, thanks for the reply, i was wondering how to connect to an already existing database (wordlist.sqlite) instead of creating a new database on the fly. i changed the openDatabase('db.sqlite', '1.0', 'Test DB', 2 * 1024 * 1024); to the existing database file located in the same folder as the index.html but it wont display anything :(

Comment: Hi Jester.  The purpose of WebSQL in HTML5 is to work with client-side databases handled by the useragent (browser).  Your SQL database on your server would be considered a server-side database, in which case you would use server-side languages such as php to manipulate it, instead of javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The database you are creating/connecting to is a **client-side** database. If you want to connect to a **back-end** database, you should use a server language, such as `php`.

You may want to use ajax with this, to connect to your database and execute your requests.